# Groovys XmlParser ignores CDATA CR/CL

Tags: java, xml, groovy, log4j

I want to parse a log4j generated xml log. Within the xml is a node with a throwable (if any). This (multiline, tabbed) text is encapsulated in a CDATA tag.

This is an excerpt of the whole file:

```
<log4j:event logger="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver" timestamp="1330083921521" level="ERROR" thread="http-8080-1">
<log4j:message><![CDATA[Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/log/show
Stacktrace follows:]]></log4j:message>
<log4j:throwable><![CDATA[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at test.LogController$_closure2.doCall(LogController.groovy:21)
    at test.LogController$_closure2.doCall(LogController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
]]></log4j:throwable>
</log4j:event>
```

I parse it with groovys XmlParser:

```
def parser = new XmlParser(false, false).parse(new File("stack.log"))

return parser.'log4j:event'.collect { l ->
    LogEntry entry = new LogEntry()
    entry.with {
        level = l.'@level'
        message = l.'log4j:message'.text()
        thread = l.'@thread'
        logger = l.'@logger'
        timestamp = new Date(l.'@timestamp' as long)
        throwable = l.'log4j:throwable'?.text() ?: ''
    }
    entry
}
```

The 'throwable' field contains all the text but without CR/LF.

Does anybody know how to cope with that?

Thanks in advcance...

Comment: Do you have a small example bit of XML?

Comment: I edited the post to show a little example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to just throw code at you, but it seems to work as expected and returns the CRLFs

```
def xml = '''<log>
            |  <log4j:event logger="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver" timestamp="1330083921521" level="ERROR" thread="http-8080-1">
            |    <log4j:message><![CDATA[Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/log/show
            |Stacktrace follows:]]></log4j:message>
            |    <log4j:throwable><![CDATA[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
            |    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
            |    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
            |    at test.LogController$_closure2.doCall(LogController.groovy:21)
            |    at test.LogController$_closure2.doCall(LogController.groovy)
            |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
            |]]></log4j:throwable>
            |  </log4j:event>
            |</log>'''.stripMargin()


class LogEntry {
  def level
  def message
  def thread
  def logger
  def timestamp
  def throwable

  String toString() {
    """EVENT:
      |  level   : $level
      |  message : $message
      |  thread  : $thread
      |  logger  : $logger
      |  ts      : $timestamp
      |  thrown  : $throwable""".stripMargin()
  }
}

def parser = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText( xml )
def entries = parser.'log4j:event'.collect { event ->
  new LogEntry().with {
    level     = event.@level
    message   = event.'log4j:message'.text()
    thread    = event.@thread
    logger    = event.@logger
    timestamp = new Date( event.@timestamp as long )
    throwable = event.'log4j:throwable'?.text() ?: ''
    it
  }
}

entries.each {
  println it
}
```

That prints:

```
EVENT:
  level   : ERROR
  message : Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/log/show
Stacktrace follows:
  thread  : http-8080-1
  logger  : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver
  ts      : Fri Feb 24 11:45:21 GMT 2012
  thrown  : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at test.LogController$_closure2.doCall(LogController.groovy:21)
    at test.LogController$_closure2.doCall(LogController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Which has CRLF chars in it where they are supposed to be...

This is with Groovy 1.8.6 btw...  What version are you using?  Can you upgrade and try again?

Comment: Hm. Yepp, on work I'm using 1.7.10 (on Grails). Testing it with 1.8.6 it works as expected.

Comment: Ok. It seems that between my controller and view i missed translating tabs etc...

Answer (score 0):

The xml standard calls for white space to be normalized during the parse.

I'm not sure, but the parser may have a setting to override this behavior.  Otherwise, you could pre-process the file, replacing line endings inside c data sections with their xml entity equivalents, and then parse it.

Comment: -1. The XML standard does **not** call for whitespace to be normalized except in attributes.